# How to overcome memory issue when plotting raster in Python

Tags: python, memory, gis, raster, rasterio

I have an i7 with 32GB and NVIDIA RTX 30 GPU.
I'm trying to plot some raster in Python and getting memory issues.
I have compressed my raster with rasterio lzw, but still getting memory issues.
My raster is boolean and already clipped the interested area.
I have transformed the raster into a dictionary with arrays.

```
for name, data in images.items():
    print(name)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(7, 7))
    if '2' in name:
        plt.imshow(data, cmap='binary', vmin=0, vmax=1)
        #plt.savefig(str(name)+'IG.png',format='png',transparent=True)
        ax.set_yticklabels([])
        ax.set_xticklabels([])
        plt.show()
    else:
        im = ax.imshow(data, cmap='viridis', vmin=0, vmax=0.8)
        cbar = fig.colorbar(im, orientation='vertical', pad=0.05)
        ax.set_yticklabels([])
        ax.set_xticklabels([])
        plt.show()
```

And I get the error:

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 7.30 GiB for an array with shape
> (62451, 31361) and data type float32

I really need to plot this data, some library, or another way to overcome this issue?

Comment: You state the data is boolean?  The memory error states the data is `float32`.  If only boolean values are needed, presumably the data can be converted to `bool` (or at least a small int type), and save *a lot* of memory usage.

Comment: Ok, I will try that, I have 0 and 1, so I guess I can change to bool. Thank you.